# Problema con DataAnnotation (DataFormatString)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema, en la visualización se me muestran los datos con el símbolo del Euro

> 123,00 €

y necesito que se visualice con el signo pesos $

> $ 123,00

Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
[Display(Name = "Salario Cargo")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal salario_cargo { get; set; }
```

Comment: qué tipo de configuración regional tiene tu computadora?

Comment: Acabo de revisar y tengo a colombia como pais y region

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```